# Highcharts adding integer instead of date

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a highcharts chart that is dynamically updated. I add the values to the series using the "AddPoint" function on the series. Here is how I am initializing the chart.

```
       var _trendToolChart = null;
        var _trendSeries = null;  



function createTrendTool() {
        _trendToolChart = Highcharts.chart('trendToolContainer', {
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                zoomType: 'x',
                panning: true,
                panKey: 'shift'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Trending Signals'
            },

            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Values'
                }

            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Time'
                },
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle'
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    label: {
                        connectorAllowed: true
                    }
                }
            },
            responsive: {
                rules: [{
                    condition: {
                    },
                    chartOptions: {
                        legend: {
                            layout: 'horizontal',
                            align: 'center',
                            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }

        });

        _trendToolChart.showLoading("Loading...");
    }
```

I keep the _trendToolChart variable as a global reference for later. On the regular I query our API to get a value. The value return is an x value of a datetime and a y value of a decimal. Since I have a multi line series, I have a WebId associated with each line on the chart itself. I find the series by this GUID, then add a point to the series.

Here's inside the function when I call it on the second:

```
 var xValue = Date.UTC(apiResponse.DateString); // convert str to date
 var yValue = apiResponse.Value;  // decimal value
 var point = [xValue, yValue];

 // add to series & graph
 var chartSeries = $.grep(_trendToolChart.series, function (e) { return e.userOptions.WebId == apiResponse.elemId; })[0];
 chartSeries.addPoint(point);
 _trendToolChart.redraw();
```

When I add these values to the chart, highcharts instead adds the x value as integer counts, *not* as a date. Here's the check inside the response function on chrome's developer side:

[image]

So instead of a series of ["11/27/2017",22] I get [0, 22] in my x values. And it shows on my chart, my xaxis labels has a "0" or 1 and not a Date.

[image]

Here's what I tried, instead of addPoint([Date,number]);, I've done addPoint ({x:Date, y:number}); Now that showed in the points on the highchart series with a date value, but then on my chart visually I saw, ZERO points added after the redraw.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it seems that the object being put in the x value was not a date, despite what it seems. It was actually a string. 
So this returns a string:

```
Date("2017-11-27")
```

As a result, highcharts didn't know how to interpret that as a datetime, since I told it to do datetime in the options. The solution was this:

```
moment("2017-11-27").ToDate()
```

This returned a proper date object, and highcharts was able to interpret.